# Multiple buttons in react-native, which one clicked

Tags: react-native

New learner, I have multiple buttons on my screen and and inside same container I have another label, on click I want to show the label and then hide after few seconds.

I am controlling through `this.state` problem is when event fires it shows all labels and then hides all. I found few solutions like assign ids etc and array for buttons.

But issue is there can be unlimited buttons so thats not the way to go to set state for each button. Or if there is any other possible way.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();

        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }
    }

    _handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: !this.state.visible
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                visible: false
            });
        },2000);
    }
      render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.item}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleClick}><Text>Button 1</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            {this.state.visible && <View style={styles.pic}>
                    <Text>Pic</Text>
                </View>
            }
        </View>

        <View style={styles.item}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleClick}><Text>Button 2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            {this.state.visible && <View style={styles.pic}>
                    <Text>Pic</Text>
                </View>
            }
        </View>


        <View style={styles.item}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleClick}><Text>Button 3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            {this.state.visible && <View style={styles.pic}>
                    <Text>Pic</Text>
                </View>
            }
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
   },
    item: {
      width: Dimensions.get("screen").width / 2,
      height: 100,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      position: 'relative',
      marginBottom: 1
  },
  pic: {
      position: 'absolute',
      right: 10,
      top: 10,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition for a simplest way. You can call the functions like this and pass parameter for check condition.

```
   onPress={()=>this._handleClick("any flag")}
```

Define function like this

```
     _handleClick(flag) { 
        if(flag == 1) {
            this.setState({state:true})
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want id based solution it means if I am having 100 buttons I have to check 100 times and on top of that how I will know which label to show :)